# Place Images behind background with HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, image

I'm making a webpage which is going to have a slideshow. And as I want it to have a fade (color-image-color). I decided to make the background to have color-alpha-color, so what I need to do is just place the images behind it and the fade will always stay there.

[image]

Now how do I place Images behind the background?

```css
body {
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/jBqKhtV.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center 1.5%;
 background-color: #141414
}

.logo {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 11;
 width: 247px;
 top: 17px;
 margin-left: -112px;
}

.headline {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 220px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 10pt;
 font-family: Lucida Sans;
 color: grey;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: normal;
}

.underline {
 width: 630px;
 height: 1px;
 background-color: white;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 margin: auto;
 top: 270px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 12
}

.navigation {
 width: 630px;
 height: 60px;
 position: aboslute;
 z-index: 13;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 margin: auto;
}

h2 {
 margin-top: 30px;
 color: white;
 font-family: Lucida Sans;
 font-size: 15pt;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 65px;
 font-weight: normal;
}

.home {
 margin-left: 68px;
}

.slideshow {
 width: 1330px;
 height: 630px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -5;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home_Stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <center>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DlXvHKb.png" class="logo">
 </center>
 
 <div class="headline">
  <h1>Cyprus Griptape Manufacturers</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="underline"></div>
 
 <div class="navigation">
  <h2 class="home">Home</h2>
  <h2>Store</h2>
  <h2>About Us</h2>
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
 </div>
 
 <div class="slideshow">
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: html css code needed

Comment: Please read [ask] first. Than add a [mcve] in the question itself. We can't inspect a picture, we need to see your existing code.

Comment: the picture is not result its the effect that I'm going for. I was just not sure if what I want is possible at all

Comment: You either haven't read the mcve link or you have seriously misunderstood its meaning. You need to add a **working** snippet (using the `<>` button. Link all the resources to it and make sure it works. Right now, it's not a working example and the contents of `Home_Stylesheet.css` as well as the technical details of your linked images (`logo.png` and `background.png`) are unknown. Expecting us to create the working example for you shows no respect for our time. We're not here to work for you for free. So please do everything you can do yourself and only leave what you don't know not done.

Comment: Sure, I should have misunderstood, must've thought that you'd be searching for faults in my code or something, anyway I'll change it now

Comment: First of all, I'm here to help you, not to find faults in your code. Second, there are several solutions for what you asked for and I wanted to take a look at your markup to decide which works best. I provided a solution that should work irrespective of your markup, by placing the background on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple, most general solution for what you want is to:

- place your slider inside a container/wrapper, giving it:

```css
.slider-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 0;
 }
```

- place a sibling of your slider in the same container, giving it:

```css
.slider-wrapper .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background effect of your choice here */
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none 
  /* this lets pointer events through, to enable interacting with the slider */
 }
```

The markup should be something like:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slider"> Your slider here </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

---

As a result, you're placing an overlay over the slider, with the desired background effect, having the same size as the contents (set by the other sibling, the slider) and not catching any `pointer-events`. That's what you wanted, right?